# trying to resize an image with react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a web app that allows users to upload images then select parameters for resizing and cropping. I've decided I'm going to handle the cropping with [react-cropper](https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper) but I can't figure out how to handle the resizing itself. Are there any packages you all would suggest? Or otherwise, can I have some advice on how to implement this in react in a way that would produce good looking images well-scaled w/ consistent aspect ratio?

I'm new to reactjs and development in general so any detailed advice on how to go about building this system would help a ton.

Thanks

react

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like `react-image-crop`. Have a look at this demo. `https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6`

Comment: Take a look at using the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Answer (score 0):

The question will be: Will you handle the image resizing / optimising on the server or within your browser?

I recently did one project that required to manipulate DOMs in the browser and export as a new image. I was using a library [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)

which can convert your React components into jpeg, png or svg. So the solution is that you handle the resizing with any React or javascript libraries like [react-resizable](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) in the browser and export the image with dom-to-image.

I hope it helps.