# How to degrade Image quality when uploading to fire-base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I built a chat app using reactJs and firebase when I upload images which size in kb it successfully uploading but when I want to upload images even sizes can be in MB,s But I want to degrade the size of these images before uploading. What is the best way I can achieve this by using reactjs?

Comment: Resizing images in React is unrelated to Firebase. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47396784 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54759082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WEBP** format of image is designed to reduce image file sizes over standard **JPEG** compression while maintaining the same or similar quality. So you can convert large image files to smaller size.

---

You can use `webp-converter`,a npm package for converting JPG, JPEG and other image formats to WEBP format.

- Install package `npm i webp-converter`
- Import module as `import webp from 'webp-converter';`.
- Implement as in a function:-

`webp.cwebp("input.jpg","output.webp","-q 80",function(status,error){
    console.log(status,error);
});`

- Push *output.webp* to firebase database.

Detailed package implementation details:-
[webp-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter)